# Installing Python command line script

Tags: python, command-line, package, conda, miniconda

I am trying to understand how to install Python packages with command line scripts. What I mean by this is installing a package with e.g. `pip install package` and then be able to run `package` while in any directory, i.e., that `package` should be on my path.

I am following [this guide](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html), which creates a minimal working example, and you install the package with `pip install .`.

There are two alternatives here, one with `console_scripts` in `entry_points`, and one with `scripts` and creating a `bin` folder and put an executable script in there. More detailed:

#### First method: `scripts`

Add a directory `bin`, in the same directory as the `funniest` package. So:

```
funniest/
    __init__.py
    text.py
bin/
    funniest-joke
```

The `funniest-joke` file is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import funniest
print(funniest.joke())
```

In `setup.py`, add `scripts=['bin/funniest-joke']` as an argument in the `setup` function call.

#### Second method: `console_scripts`

Add a `command_line.py` file alongside `text.py` and `__init__.py`, which is

```
import funniest

def main():
    print funniest.joke()
```

In `setup.py`, add this as an argument to the `setup` function call:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'funniest-joke = funniest.command_line:main'
    ],
},
```

The problem is that I can't get any of these to work. The packages install just fine, but I do not get an executable on my path, and it does not even seem to put anything in any `/bin/` directory. There should be a `funniest-joke` on my path, but there is not.

For information:
I am using a miniconda installed Python, which is at `~/miniconda3/`, so my `pip`, which I use to install the packages, is at `~/miniconda3/bin`, and Python is also the one at `~/miniconda3/bin`.

The package (`funniest`) is installed into `/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/funniest`.

My path contains the following directories.

```
/bin/
/usr/local/bin/python
/Users/USERNAME/miniconda3/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
```

Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: So you're basically running a Python script from a previously activated conda env.
Running the python script you would like to be able to install, for example, wget.
Normally you'd do pip install wget and here, if I understood it well, you want to do it programmatically from python, right?

Comment: @Pitto No, it's actually not in any environment, if I understand it correctly. I just installed the miniconda distribution of Python, as opposed to using the built-in (macOS) Python or the Homebrew Python. I suppose conda acts as a package manager.

As for the second point: I see that's not clear. I do mean that I want to do it similar to `pip install wget`, and then be able to run `wget` from the command line (while in any directory).

Comment: @Pitto I added some clarification in the first paragraph. Is it clear?

Comment: You mention two methods for scripts (entry_points or scripts in a bin directory) but you then don't say which method you are trying to follow.  For the former, how `setup.py` is defined is crucial.  If you want to use that method, please include some detail of your current setup.py. Ah, but before that, clarify which route you want to use!

Comment: @Bonlenfum Oh, sorry. I did the exact same thing as in the tutorial. I'll add it in the post.

Comment: I just tried a similar project and it worked with both routes, including with both routes simultaneously. Note that if you include both routes in setup.py, the entry_points generated script 'wins' - I was expecting there to be a clash with defining both but pip handles it ok.  I used [this template](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py) for setup.py. Perhaps yours differs drastically from this?

Comment: ah, one more thing that you can look at is the pip ouput while installing: `pip install . -vvv` for maximum output.  It shows a lot, and maybe a useful hint is to try the uninstall operation afterwards, which tells you what it is removing (asking for confirmation first).  Maybe that will tell you where it has put the scripts, and you'll see something different than you expected in the paths

Comment: @Bonlenfum Thanks a lot for that verbose output tip!! I was able to fix it now! The scripts are installed into `~/bin` (i.e. `/Users/USERNAME/bin`), and this was not on my path. I just needed to add it to my path. I thought I had already done that, and that I shouldn't because it also contains the system Python, but it works fine!

Comment: @vegardstikbakke You should consider writing your own answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

When you enter in the terminal:

```sh
which python
```

The example will show you the location of the default python you are using.
By what you have said your result will probably be:

```
/Users/USERNAME/miniconda3/bin/python
```

That being said, if you enter:

```sh
which executable
```

for any executable, the terminal will show you where it is installed. I hope that helps.

Comment: I guess that wasn't clear. Both `python` and `pip` are located at `miniconda3/bin`.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to follow the path to install the package in python.
But you need to follow this way
1. first install python on pc
2. simple Open command prompt then type pip install (---python package name----)
3. then press Enter button but make sure internet is available.

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't very helpful, unfortunately. The question you're answering is how to install packages which are on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org).